# Convergence of joint distribution and measurability implies convergence in probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory

currently I started to ask myself the following question motivated by this classical exercise:

> Suppose that $(Y_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ is a sequence of random variables defined on the same probability space such that $Y_n \to c$ in distribution as $n \to \infty$ where $c \in \mathbb R$ is a constant then $Y_n \to c$ in probability.

Now change the setup in the following sense:

Instead of $Y_n \to c$ we introduce another random variable $X$ on the same probability space and require that $(X,Y_n) \to (X,Y)$ in distribution as $n \to \infty$. Now in order to compare this to the classical exercise above we introduce the fact that $Y$ is measurable  with respect to $X$. In that sense it is not constant as before but varies ''random constantly'', now we precisely formulate this as the following exercise.

**Exercise**:

Let $X$, $Y$ and $\{Y_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$ be random variables defined on the same probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb P)$. Assume that $(X, Y_n) \to (X,Y)$ in distribution as $n \to \infty$. Show that if $Y$ is a measurable function of $X$, then $Y_n \to Y$ in probability as $n \to \infty$.

**My attempt**: I have trouble writing this quite precisely but intuitively it is clear. Since one has the following
$$
(X,Y_n) \stackrel{(d)}{\to} (X,Y) = (X,f(X)) \quad \text{ as } n \to \infty,
$$
then fixing one realization given by $X = c$ this is basically the classical exercise from above. In this setting with $X=c$ one has $Y_n \to c$ in probability as $n \to \infty$ conditional on given that $X = c$ but integrating over all the choices of $X=c$ yields everything you need. Maybe one can write
$$
P(|Y_n - Y| < \epsilon) = (P \otimes P)\left((X,Y_n) \in \mathbb R \times [-\epsilon + f(X), \epsilon + f(X)]\right),
$$
but now using properties of the product measure yields that the right hand side is nothing different than
$$
\int_{\mathbb R} P(f(x)-\epsilon < Y_n < f(x)+\epsilon) dP_{X}(x), 
$$
using the assumption we also know that $Y_n \to Y$ in distribution, hence since inside the integral $f(x) \in \mathbb R$ is fixed, we know that as $\epsilon \to 0$ the inside is equal to constant $1$, thus integrating over this constant we get the desired.

**Question**: How can you write this better?